# "Location method" does not change in Android O devices when grant location permissions

Tags: android

I have this app which request location permission to use Google API Services. I've notice there is a weird behavior when I have the following conditions:

1.- Android O devices.
2.- App location permissions has to be enabled.
3.- Device location permissions has to be on.
4.- Device location method has to be set to other than "High accuracy" (could be "Battery saving" or "Phone only"). <- This is the important one.

As in the app, inside my fragment, the LocationRequest object I set priority as: PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, Android will show pop up to notify the user location permission have to be granted. The problem here is, it seems, as device location is already on, Android doesn't do anything and does not change the location method, so, locations setting still not satisfied, so it keeps showing the pop up to request permission.
The funny thing is that if you have your location method "Battery saving" or "Phone only" but the device location is turn off, previous exercise works fine, turns on location and change the location method to High Accuracy.

Is this an Android O limitation?

Note: Android P doesn't have this problem as they got rid off "Location method" on location settings.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue in android 8.0 and 8.1 devices.
I solved the issue by changing the location mode to Battery Saving.

```
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```